# The example of a mapping is homomorphic but not isomorphic

Tags: banach-spaces

The example of two Banach space A,B such that the mapping  T:A→B, is onto , one-to-one and homomorphic but not isomorphic i.e ∥T(x)∥≠∥x∥.
I think there are two norm spaces, such that norm does not lead to the inner product.

Comment: You mean isometric, not isomorphic I assume, since the open-mapping theorem implies that the inverse is continuous.

Comment: Let $A=B=\Bbb R$ and $T(x)=2x$.

Comment: @AdamHughes: You should write that as an answer.

Comment: @Michael Albanese Okie dokie.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=B=\Bbb R$ and $T(x)=2x$.